# System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo wrong model type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i create the correct model type and dont understand where this comes from. any ideas?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BusinessLogic.Models.ErrorCodeModel'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary)
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.c__DisplayClass6.c__DisplayClassb.b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

in the global.asax.cs i register a custom attribute:

```
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new Controllers.ExtendendHandleErrorAttribute());
        }
```

the definition looks like this:

```
public class ExtendendHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {                                   
            LogErrors(filterContext);
            try
            {
                base.OnException(filterContext);

                var typedResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
                if (typedResult != null)
                {
                    var tmpModel = typedResult.ViewData.Model;
                    typedResult.ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
                    typedResult.ViewData.Model = CreateModel(filterContext);
                    filterContext.Result = typedResult;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                new LogManager().Log("ExtendendHandleErrorAttribute error", ex);
            }
        }
```

interesting here that i create the ErrorCodeModel.

```
        private ErrorCodeModel CreateModel(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var model = new ErrorCodeModel(); 

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;

                model.SessionId = session.SessionID;
                StateHandler stateHandler = new StateHandler(session);
                model.FapiErrorCode = stateHandler.CustomErrorCode.ToString();               
                try
                {                    
                    model.GlobalData = new GlobalDataBuilder(stateHandler).Build();
                    model.ErrorMessage = model.GlobalData.ErrorText.TechnicalError;
                }
                catch { }
            }

            return model;
        }
```

my Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error/FileNotFound" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly your scenario, what you are trying to achieve, what you did in order to achieve it and what didn't work? Well, for the last part you already showed the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` replace the first line:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
```

with

```
@model BusinessLogic.Models.ErrorCodeModel
```

Comment: My Error.cshtml has a custom @model in it and I still get the error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `[HandleError]` attribute on a controller or action, any exceptions thrown will cause a redirect to custom error pages as described by your web.config. By default the errors go to the `~\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml` using the `HandleErrorInfo` model.

The web.config section can be something like:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm"/>
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm"/>
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://bakingwebsites.co.uk/2011/02/10/how-to-handle-the-mvc-httpantiforgeryexception/